# Slow Partnerconnection response

Tags: data-loader, partner-wsdl

I am developing a custom app for my organisation based on Partner API.

In my org, the case object has large number of fields (70+).

The custom app takes almost a day to fetch 26000 case records whereas the DATA Loader takes hardly 10 mins to query the same 26000 records.

Knowing the fact that DATA Loader is built using Partner API, I am unable to understand why my custom app takes a whole day to finish?

where am I missing?

Below is the code

```
PartnerConnection conn = StartProcess.getConnection();
String query = "Select (all fields)";
query = query+" from "+ case;
boolean done = false;
conn.setQueryOptions(500);                  
QueryResult qr = conn.query(query);
while (!done) 
{
SObject[] records = qr.getRecords();
if (qr.isDone())
{
done = true;
} 
else
{
 qr = conn.queryMore(qr.getQueryLocator());
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce may alter the QueryResult batch size based on the fields selected. For example, selecting an Attachment Body reduces the size to 1. Fields with the long text type will also reduce the batch size.

From [Change the Batch Size in Queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_changing_batch_size.htm) (my emphasis):

> The maximum batch size is 2,000 records. **However this setting is only a suggestion. There is no guarantee that the requested batch size will be the actual batch size.** This is done to maximize performance.
>
> ## Note
>
> **The batch size will be no more than 200 if the SOQL statement selects two or more custom fields of type long text**. This is to prevent large SOAP messages from being returned.

---

It looks like you are using Java and the example in [SOAP Compression](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/SOAP_Compression) is for really old versions of .NET, but the principal is the same. You should be compressing the request and indicating that you accept a compressed response. With large payloads the compression can save significant time.

Your comment that you needed to reduce the query batch size to get a timely response makes me think this may be a significant factor in your app.

---

What are you doing with the queried SObject records within the loop? I assume you are doing actual work rather than just looping over all 26,000 records. Is there something in the loop that is consuming and then releasing large amounts of memory? If so, there could be garbage collection overhead as well.

The [QueryLocator](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_query_querylocator.htm#topic-title) will timeout after 15 minutes on inactivity, which makes me think none of the query mote loops takes longer than that.

---

Have you tried the same query in other tools beyond the data loader?

Make sure the query is *exactly* the same, with all the required fields.

Workbench and the Developer console would both be good test cases, but I suspect they are using the REST API for SOQL queries.

I do know that the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/en/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-SOQL-Queries.aspx) uses the Partner SOAP API to execute SOQL queries and will page through all the results. You could use it as a separate verification of how long the query takes. (Full disclosure: I work for the company that makes this tool).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting your batch size 'setQueryOptions' to 500?  The Max Limit is 2,000,  so with that being said you most likely won't be getting 2000 records because in the end it depends on the load the SFDC servers are dealing with.

Also one thing you should be exploring is whether or not you really need to query the 70+ fields, and another question is..  This a custom mobile app? How are users going to efficiently navigate 70+ fields?

But to sum it up, Change your batch size limit.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Its is not a custom mobile app. i am trying to make a desktop app like Data loader. I started testing the app with 2000 batch size and the response came very late, so late that using the app was a waste of time. This made me believe that reducing the batch size would help in receiving fast response because servers would have to process less records and hence give better performance . But even this didn't help. The requirement is such that all fields are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should turn yourself in the direction of using Bulk API. A tool that can do work like Data Loader should utilize Bulk API instead of regular Partner API.

[Force.com Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Loading_Large_Data_Sets_with_the_Force.com_Bulk_API)

[Force.com Bulk API - General Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Bulk_API)